# An exception in Grizzly unit test with Jersey

Tags: java, junit, jersey, grizzly, jersey-2.0

I'm running `Unit Test` to test my `RESTful` web service run with `Grizzly`, and get the following exception.

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:917)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:770)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:296)
    at com.example.MyResourceTest.testGetIt(MyResourceTest.java:45)
```

The Unit Test

```
package com.example;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import java.net.URI;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MyResourceTest {
    public static final URI BASE_URI = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost").port(8080).build();
    private HttpServer server;
    private WebTarget target;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
        server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);

        server.start();
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        target = c.target(BASE_URI);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Test to see that the message "Got it!" is sent in the response.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetIt() {
        String responseMsg = target.path("myresource").request().get(String.class); // <--- line 45 in exception!!!
        assertEquals("Got it!", responseMsg);
    }
}
```

And the REST service

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

And `dependencies` from `POM.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

**I FIXED IT!**

I needed this:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class); //This is resource class
```

instead of:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
```

And now I'm using only these `dependencies` in `POM.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thanks, for attention!